# How to have jquery add a panel inside a panel in Bootstrap v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running through a loop, and appending text from an array into a main panel, but I want so that each "chunk" of text is inside it's own panel.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="panel no-overflow">
    <p id="fromTweets"> imported text goes here</p>
</div>
```

My JQUERY:

```
for (i = 0; i < result.statuses.length; i++) {    
    //Print out username and status
    $("#fromTweets").append('<b>' + "Username: " + '</b>' + result.statuses[i].user.screen_name + '<br/>');
    $("#fromTweets").append('<b>' + "Tweet: " + '</b>' +   result.statuses[i].text + '<br/>');
}
```

Also, I guess I'm more generally confused with using css and jquery with the "append" way. Notice how I'm bolding text using `<b>`, is this bad practice, is there a better way to do this? Same question for the `<br>` tag.

Comment: As a quick comment, <b> can often be replaced with <strong>

Comment: @OliverRadini `<strong>` should be used if you mean strong emphasis, which is not the case here. While a `<span>` with a class would be preferred, `<b>` is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for he clarification - for the record, I didn't mean to imply that he ought to change it, only that it was a potential option. I've since learnt more about the apropriate times to use <b> <strong> and spanning and in retrospect my original comment was rather unhelpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably best to create a div to which you can append panels. For instance:

```
<div class="panel-holder">
```

You can then use the append to append not just text, but a div tag with the class 'panel'.

Here's a fiddle with a quick demonstration:

https://jsfiddle.net/oq2bfyam/1/